# SQLITE - To view the updates that have just been made to the application, it is necessary to sign out and sign in again

Tags: python, sqlite, view, kivy

I can normally update the records in the SQLITE database, the problem is when I view the updated record, it brings the old information, to bring the updated information it is necessary to exit the application and return.

What do I need to do to make the application automatically recognize changes made without having to leave?

***DATA UPDATE CODE***:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("datum.db") 
cursor = conn.cursor()
highestscore =  cursor.execute("""select highest_score from datum where id_score = 1""")
highestscore = cursor.fetchone()
highestscore = highestscore[0]
if self.score > highestscore:
    highestscore = self.score
atualizar = cursor.execute("""UPDATE datum SET highest_score = ?, last_score = ?;""", (highestscore,self.score,))
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

***DATA DISPLAY CODE***:

```
try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect("datum.db") 
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    hscore = cursor.execute("""select highest_score from datum where id_score = 1""")
    hscore = cursor.fetchone()
    hscore = hscore[0]
    cursor.close()
except:
    conn = sqlite3.connect('datum.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE datum(id_score INTEGER NOT NULL, highest_score INTEGER, last_score INTEGER);""")
    except:
        pass
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO datum(id_score, highest_score, last_score) VALUES(1, 0, 0);""")
    conn.commit()
    hscore = cursor.execute("""select highest_score from datum where id_score = 1""")
    hscore = cursor.fetchone()
    hscore = hscore[0]
    cursor.close()
```

Comment: It's hard to answer this question, because the full flow of you app is not clear. It's worth noting, though, that placing 6 separate statements in a `try` block, and only catching the most generic exception (i.e., `except:` without any exception type), is a surefire way of catching unintended exceptions. This is especially true when at least 3 of these statements can raise exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to approach Database Application is to create a class of Database(Separate module for the database) inside that class you can have insert, update, delete, display methods(OR any other you want). This way you can access the updated data.